# How to compute the maximum average for a certain period of time in R?

Tags: r

I am working with this data in R:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dl/chmzqmus6bfoaim/climate_clean.csv

I wanted to know how to compute the maximum average monthly temperature by year in Europe. Here we have to take into account the variable `average_temperature_celcius` meaning the average monthly temperature and the observation `"Europe"` which is apart of the variable `"Continent"`.

I want to do the average temperature in celsius for each month over all European countries and take the month with the maximum average for each year and produce a boxplot displaying these maxima yearly temperatures to see how many outliers are there.

First of all, I subsetted the data frame `climate` to only keep the variable `Continent == "Europe"`.

Then I selected only the variables `average_temperature_celcius`, `Continent` and `year`.

```r
Europe = climate[climate$continent == "Europe", ]
Europebis = select(Europe, year,average_temperature_celsius, month)
```

Finnaly I grouped by to have a more coherent data frame

```r
Europebis2 = group_by(Europebis, year, month)
EUROPE = summarise(Europebis2, meany = mean(average_temperature_celsius)
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Which structure should have the dataframe you expect? What have you tried? (take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually, I need to make it into a boxplot, to see how many 'outliers' are there. First of all, I subset the data climate to  only keep the Continent = Europe. Then I selected only the variables "average_temperature_celcius", "Continent" and "year".    Europe = climate[climate$continent == "Europe", ].        Europebis = select(Europe, year,average_temperature_celsius, month)
Europebis2 = group_by(Europebis, year, month)
EUROPE = summarise(Europebis2, meany = mean(average_temperature_celsius))
View(Europebis2)

Comment: You may want to add that code to the question's body. Besides, do you want to do the average for each month over all countries and take the month with the maximum average for each year?, do you want to do the average for each country over all months and take the country with the maximum average for each year? or countries have nothing to do and you want to make the average over all countries and months for each year and take the year with the maximum average?

Comment: I finally learned how to write in code on stackoverflow thank u ! I want to do the average temperature in celsius for each month over all European countries and take the month with the maximum average for each year and produce a boxplot displaying these maxima yearly temperatures to see how many outliers are there.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```r
library(dplyr)
climate %>%
    filter(continent == "Europe") %>% # keep only european countries data
    group_by(year, month) %>% # next, take the average temperature in celsius for each month over all countries
    summarise(across(c(average_temperature_celsius), mean)) %>%
    group_by(year) %>% # next take the month with the maximum average for each year
    summarise(across(c(average_temperature_celsius), max)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = average_temperature_celsius)) + 
    geom_boxplot()
```

In order to edit your boxplot, you can take a look at http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-box-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Comment: ````climate %>%
  filter(continent == "Europe") %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(average_temperature_celsius), mean)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(average_temperature_celsius), max))%>%
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = average_temperature_celsius)) + 
  geom_boxplot()```` 
 I did it only with the mean to compare the two boxplot
````climate %>%
  filter(continent == "Europe") %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  summarise(across(c(average_temperature_celsius), mean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = average_temperature_celsius)) + 
  geom_boxplot()````

Comment: So I obtained one boxplot with the maximum mean average temperature per month by year among european countries and another boxplot with the mean average temperature per month by year among european countries. I did not find any outliers did you find any ?

Comment: No, I didn't. If the answer solves your question you may accept it.